# How was this snare made?

Tags: sound, sample

I'm wondering how this sample was made? Is it just a snare with A LOT of reverb on it? I've tried doing it but i just can't get it right! http://www.mediafire.com/listen/4gzuhv9m4hrnbbq/DROP_SNARE_128_BPM_F.wav
Similar sample used here

I know i can just use a sample if i want to use it but i really want to know how it was made!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's essentially correct. The recipe for effecting is simple: add a lot of reverb and compression to even out the overall volume — and at times, a reversed copy to make it suck/whoosh backwards.

This is known as a variation of the "Pryda Snare", as famously used by Eric Prydz in "Miami To Atlanta". YouTube presents possible paths to achieve such a result: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pryda+snare&search=Search

Broader then this, there is tremendous power in being able to control reverb tails after drum hits. Part of this harkens back to gated reverbs as famously used in the 80s by Phil Collins and others. I encourage you to read more on the history to understand it evolved into the sound we have today.

EDIT: To whoever downvoted the original post, I am curious as to why. Is it because you don't like the sound, since it's an integral part of popular EDM?

Comment: Let's upvote it back =)

Comment: Please don't assume it's a 'because ou don't like the sound, since it's an integral part of popular EDM?'. Downvoting on stack exchange is a tool used to help shape questions and help getting better answers. it's not used for promoting opinions. 
I downvoted because the question was not very well asked, as there was no information on what was tried before (except the use of reverb, which seems obvious imho). 
And the question is 'off topic' because this is a sound design forum, these kinds of questions are better suited for other forums and youtube tutorials.

Comment: Arnoud Traa, you misunderstand. I did not assume, I asked for clarification: "Is it because... ?" While I have seen vague questions on here before, this was clearly asked, with a YouTube video linked to the specific timecode. What seems obvious to your wealth of experience may not be so for a newcomer, so given good intentions and community spirit, I'd rather give the benefit of the doubt — and I did point torritorri to YouTube tutorials, now that he knows the name "Pryda snare" to continue his research. I do appreciate your explanation, that is more helpful than a context-less downvote. :)

Comment: Hi Torley, thanks for your response, somehow stack exchange is not notifying me for new messages and I missed this comment. Regarding your question, perhaps i misunderstood because I thought i saw some subtext in your wording. EDM is bashed upon in a lot of places and I thought you were responding out of that 'emotion'. I was wrong, so i apologize. Nevertheless, I still don't feel this is a question for sound design.

Comment: Also two things that might help to get it sounding huge: gated white noise send into reverb. You do not need to use the dry white noise just the reverb of it. And slightly distort reverb and snare together. This will bring out the harmonics of the room -> it Sounds thicker.

Comment: Just a heads up @ArnoudTraa, you didn't get notified because 1) you were not the OP of the answer, and 2) TORLEY didn't use the @ to tag your username...  carry on ;)